# SingleChildScrollView is limiting the height of Container to the children despite using Expanded inside Row()

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, vertical-scrolling, singlechildscrollview

There are two containers inside the row wrapped with expanded but when SingleChildScrollView above Row is used the height of containers is reduced to its children.

Without SingleChildScrollView the output is like this but not scrollable.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width;
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height;

    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        // height: screenHeight,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: mainLightColor,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Image(
                        width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width * 0.22,
                        height: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width * 0.22,
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        image: const AssetImage('assets/images/logo.png')),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: blackColor,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: screenWidth * 0.2,
                      height: 35,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
                        color: mainMediumColor,
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Create Account',
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: screenWidth * 0.2,
                      height: 35,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
                        border: Border.all(color: mainMediumColor),
                        color: blackColor,
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Log In',
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(color: whiteColor),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )));
  }
}
```

Without Using SingleChildScrollView the output is like this

[image: W]

Using SingleChildScrollView the output is like this

[image]

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width;
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height;

    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          // height: screenHeight,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: mainLightColor,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Image(
                          width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width * 0.22,
                          height: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width * 0.22,
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          image: const AssetImage('assets/images/logo.png')),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: blackColor,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: screenWidth * 0.2,
                        height: 35,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
                          color: mainMediumColor,
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Create Account',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: screenWidth * 0.2,
                        height: 35,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
                          border: Border.all(color: mainMediumColor),
                          color: blackColor,
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Log In',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(color: whiteColor),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )));
  }
}
```

I want full height of the container with scrolling but SingleChildScrollView decreases it according to the height of children.

I provided container with screenHeight but it did not work.

Any Solution? Thanks

Comment: check the code samples in [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) official documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `ConstrainedBox` and `IntrinsicHeight`. Replace

```
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          // height: screenHeight,
          child: Row(
```

with

```
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: screenHeight),
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Row(
```

Comment: Instantly Solved the Problem, Thanks for Sharing this Golden Tip. I heard from senior devs that we should avoid IntrinsicHeight Widget because it causes a lot of problems. Is it true?

Comment: It's true that it costs a bit of performance but sometimes there's no other way, and it also doesn't matter when there's not that many subwidgets under it. The performance loss will be negligible

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this problem? Because the IntrinsicHeight widget does not support LayoutBuilder inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Constraints` inside the `Container` :

```
Container(
constraints:BoxConstraints(
minWidth: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width,
minHeight: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height,
),
child:....
)
```

use `height` and `width` according to your `requirements`